# Changing the default file path for gcc compiler

Tags: bash, compiling, gcc, paths

I'm trying to compile a file named "filename.c" and as far as I know, it has to be in the Home folder when I use the command:

```
gcc filename.c -o filename
```

Alternatively, I would have to specify file path, for example, if filename.c was on my desktop and I wanted the excecutable file to be saved on desktop:

```
gcc /home/username/Desktop/filename.c -o /home/username/Desktop/filename
```

So far, this has worked fine but my Home folder is getting quite cluttered and I would like to move all my .c files and executables to another folder. However, I would like to avoid writing out the file path every time I compile a code. Is there a way that I could change the default file path to a certain folder?

Essentially what I would like is to type the first command and by default, the compiler would perform the second command. I am quite new to Ubuntu so I apologize if this is a silly question but I have been so impressed with what's possible on Ubuntu, I thought it was worth asking.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The default build directory is `/home/name/tmp/` with a folder for each project in `tmp/`. ... If you e.g. can have the executable´s in tmp/ : `cd tmp/new/ && gcc filename.c -o ../filename` ... i.e. two periods ( .. ) means one level up.

Comment: If you use `make` rather than invoking `gcc` directly, you could use `VPATH` to specify the *source* directory - however the *target* (executable) will still be generated in your current directory.

Comment: Thank you @KnudLarsen as a temporary solution, that is very helpful!

Comment: @steeldriver thank you! That is almost exactly what I was looking for! I appreciate it!